# How to call value from ID column to add on new string

Tags: mysql

Our Wordpress database has a column `guid` with value:

`http://localhost/wordpress1/?p=x`,

where `x` is an `id` value. For example, if `id = 1` then `guid = http://localhost/wordpress1/?p=1`

The following code :

```
$query = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 
                path-to-folder
                INTO TABLE wp_posts
                FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
                LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
                IGNORE 1 LINES
                (post_author,post_content,post_title) 
                SET guid = 'http://localhost/wordpress1/?p='id";
```

throws an error. Please assist to correct the SET command.

Comment: What error do you have?

Comment: `1` is not a [GUID](http://guid.one/guid). Neither is `'http://localhost/wordpress1/?p='`. And it looks like you maybe have a syntax error becuase of the stray `id` after the quote mark (i.e. `?p='id` - `id` is outside the quote mark. But yes please tell us your exact error message, so we can be more certain.

Comment: Yes, what I need is correct syntax in this query , I don't know how to show value of  column 'id' in that syntax .